# Un mot français pour week-end ?

Tags: usage, anglicismes, indications-de-temps

Je viens de lire [un article sur le mot *week-end*](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/vocabulary/mot-du-jour/week-end/) et je me demande s'il existe, ou s'il existait, un mot (peut-être une expression) en français pour *week-end*. Selon cet article, comme il s'agit de franglais, l'expression est informelle. Comment dit-on alors *week-end* dans une situation formelle ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Bien qu'il ne soit pas encore dans [le neuvième de l'Académie du CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/week-end), *week-end* est l'usage courant en Français et est très bien attesté par le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/week-end). C'est donc un mot français, aussi loin que je suis concerné.

> **Week-end**, subst. masc.
>
> A. − Fin de semaine (du samedi matin ou midi au dimanche soir) chômée et considérée comme une période de repos, de sorties, et de loisirs. […]

Il semble cependant qu'on lui préfère *fin de semaine* au Québec (à attester par des locuteurs natifs)

> **Rem.** Au Québec, on utilise le plus souvent, au sens A, le synon. *fin de semaine*.

Ne pas confondre avec *fin de la semaine* qui désigne plutôt la fin de la semaine ouvrable, donc le jeudi et le vendredi. En France, c'est aussi le sens qu'a *fin de semaine* en général.

En contexte formel, *week-end* est tout à fait acceptable.

Comment: J'atteste l'usage de *fin de semaine* au Québec, mais *week-end* est utilisé également.

Comment: Au Québec j'entends seulment _fin de semaine_, comme «bon fin de semaine». J'ai jamais entendu _weekend_, mais ma femme m'a expliqué que parfois on utilise _fin de semaine_ pour **jeudi,vendredi,samedi et dimanche** et _weekend_ spécifiquement pour **samedi et dimanche**.

Comment: @Micromégas "bonne fin de semaine"*

Comment: Et je confirme aussi que "fin de semaine" est beaucoup utilisé au Québec.

Comment: En France (pas au Quebec) je deconseille fortement d'employer "weekend" et "fin de semaine" de maniere interchangeable. "Fin de semaine" en France couvre une periode vague recouvrant samedi et dimanche, mais souvent aussi vendredi et parfois jeudi.

Comment: Pour moi la fin de semaine ne contient que des jours ouvrés (jeudi et vendredi), c'est-à-dire distincts du week-end.

Comment: Au Québec, "fin de la semaine" va signifier jeudi/vendredi et "fin de semaine" désigne samedi/dimanche (plus congé férié s'il y a, par example "une fin de semaine de trois jours")

Comment: @Evpok: « aussi loin que je suis concerné » ???

Comment: @octosquidopus Une copie carbone intéressante, n'est-il pas ?

Comment: Je pense que le plus clair et précis est "congé de fin de semaine". Simplement "fin de semaine" n'est pas suffisemment précis (on peut comprendre "la deuxième moitié de la semaine").

Comment: @berty, Ce n'est pas utilisé comme çà. Si nous avons besoin de distinguer les jours finals de la semaine du weekend, nous utilisons "fin de la semaine" au lieu de "fin de semaine". [Nouveau-Brunswick]

Answer (score 9):

Je rejoins les deux réponses déjà formulées : même dans une situation formelle, on dira *week-end*. Par exemple, même Légifrance (portail de la législation et réglementation française) trouve un [grand nombre](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=week-end+site:legifrance.gouv.fr&pbx=1&oq=week-end+site:legifrance.gouv.fr&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=333l4875l0l5041l16l15l0l0l0l0l172l1263l10.5l15l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4c725250c2b9ff20&biw=1340&bih=817) de textes réglementaires qui comportent l'expression.

Une recherche avec [Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=week+end&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=6) révèle que, pour l'usage écrit, l'expression a décollé dans le premier quart du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle :

[image: ngram]

Answer (score 2):

En grec le "week end" est un mot qui vient du Samedi (to Savvato)  et le Dimanche (i kiriaki). Et le mot est "to savvatokiriako". Vous pourriez faire une combinaison telle, et produire le mot "le Samedimanche" :)))

Comment: « Samedimanche » est pas mal, mais un peu long. Surtout, il ne peut pas s'appliquer aux week-ends prolongés. Pourquoi pas « hebdopause » ?

Comment: Je trouve que ça ressemble un peu trop à "Ça m'démange"

Answer (score 2):

Voici toutes les suggestions que j'ai glanées sur la toile pour remplacer l'expression 'Bon week-end !' : Bon congé de fin de semaine ! (souvent utilisé par des organismes de défense de la langue française) / Bon repos de fin de semaine ! / Bon samedime ! (Bon samdim !) / Bon samedimanche ! / Bon samanche ! / Bonne dimanchade ! (inspiré du provençal : dimenchado) / Bonne(s) vacancelle(s) ! / Bonne dominique ! / Bonnes reposailles ! / Bonne hebdopause ! (mot inventé par l'écrivain belge Roger Constantin dans son texte 'L'Ombre du fantôme', Académie Balzac) / Bonne fin-semaine ! Alors, faites votre choix et surtout n'hésitez pas à les diffuser sur la toile. Je ne vous cache pas que mon petit préféré est : BONNE HEBDOPAUSE ! ;-)

Récapitulatif : https://www.pinterest.fr/pin/319051954857050484/

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue sur FSE ! Serait-il possible de rendre cette réponse plus concise et d'en retirer les aspects qui dérivent du sujet pour tendre vers un débat sur les anglicismes dans la langue française ? L'objectif de ce site est d'apporter des réponses claires mais les débats ont plutôt leur place dans le [chat].

Comment: Voilà, commentaire rectifié. Bon congé de fin de semaine!

Comment: Merci et bonne dimanchade !

Answer (score 1):

On utilise « bon weekend » en français aussi.

Answer (score 1):

"Vacancettes" fait partie de la liste des propositions au concours pour la Défense de la Langue française organisé par l'Académie des Sciences, Inscriptions et Belles-Lettres de Toulouse, gagné par les lycéens d'une classe de Seconde du lycée Déodat-de-Séverac de Toulouse.

[Défense de la langue française](http://www.site-magister.com/vocabcd2.htm)

Comment: Pour autant que je sache, l'Académie n'a jamais proposé le mot *vacancette*. On n'en trouve aucune trace sur leur site [web](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/ecrans-et-toiles). Il s'agit en fait d'une [proposition par des lycéens](http://www.site-magister.com/vocabcd2.htm) ! Même si cette proposition a fait partie d'une liste qui a remporté un concours organisé par l'Académie de Toulouse, la connexion avec l'Académie est tenue et il ne s'agit un aucun cas d'une proposition officielle. En plus, la plupart des francophones comprendront « vacance courte » et non « week-end ».

Answer (score 1):

J'ai déjà entendu "dominique" pour week-end.

Comment: Hein ? Ça fait penser à *dominical*, l'adjectif qui veut dire « ayant rapport au dimanche ». Mais le nom correspondant est *dimanche*, pas *dominique*, et ça n'inclut pas le samedi.

Comment: J'ai entendu ce mot chez des personnes cherchant à éviter les anglicismes. Dans ce cas précis "la dominique" remplaçait "le week-end".

Answer (score 1):

Conscient que ma réponse n’est pas académique, je pensais qu’elle pourrait être utile à quiconque se poserait la même question que Beatrix.

En l’occurence, j’ai forgé le néologisme [*samanche*](http://taniere.info/littera/idiolecte/neologisme/#Samanche), contraction de **sam**edi et dim**anche**. Mais bien entendu il ne faut pas (encore) l’utiliser dans des situations formelles.

Comment: Désolé de réagir 5 ans plus tard (ce n'est pas moi qui ai déterré cette question), mais même si je trouve votre créativité sympathique, si la création de ces néologismes a pour but la défense de la langue francaise, je commencerais par corriger la phrase d'introduction sur la page que vous liez : "Ceci est le glossaire des néologismes que j’ai créés pour les utilisés dans un seul ouvrage"; "...pour les utilisés..." fait très mal aux yeux...

Comment: Conformément aux règles de StackExchange, je vous invite à poursuivre cette discussion en privée, à travers l’adresse de courriel que vous trouverez sur ce même site :) Je supprimerais ce message dès que je recevrais un courriel de votre part.

Answer (score 1):

Les gens, vos néologismes manquent de classe et de prestance. Pour ça, il faut prendre des racines latines voire grecques en fusionnant fin et semaine :
hebdomadîtelos/septimanaefinis, abrégé en septifini c'est plus mignon.

Comment: D'où provienne hebdomadîtelos et septimanaefinis ? Mon moteur de recherche ne renvoi que ce message SE comme résultat :O

Answer (score 1):

Que diriez-vous du sabadon ?

Créé avec le sabbat (samedi) et le jour dominical (dimanche).

Comment: Est-ce que ce néologisme répond à la question, « Comment dit-on week-end dans une situation formelle ? »

Answer (score 1):

Pour comprendre quand, comment et pourquoi cette expression anglaise a été adoptée en français, il faut considérer cette autre expression : « [semaine anglaise](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/semaine_anglaise) », ainsi que le contexte économique et social dans lequel a été adoptée la [Loi des huit heures](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_des_huit_heures).

Answer (score 1):

Utilisons donc tout simplement SAMDIM

Comment: Est-ce que ce néologisme répond à la question, « Comment dit-on week-end dans une situation formelle ? »

Answer (score -1):

J'aime *la Dominique*, mais ***la petite semaine*** aurait du potentiel aussi, par analogie avec *petit lait*, *petit(e) ami(e)* ou *petite reine* (l'adjectif suggère l'affection au lieu du sens littéral habituel).

Answer (score -2):

Pourquoi ne pas contracter samedi et dimanche en mot-valise : SAMedimANCHE, samanche, deux syllabes, comme week-end. "Je pars en samanche".

Answer (score -2):

Fatigué des anglicismes depuis longtemps j'ai depuis tout aussi longtemps forgé le terme samedanche qui se prononce en 2 syllabes. Essayez-le, il a une sonorité populaire et va certainement vous plaire ! Bon samedanche à tous .

Comment: Ceci est un néologisme d'utilisation très restreinte (*a priori* un seul locuteur) alors que la question était : « Comment dit-on alors week-end dans une situation formelle ? »

Comment: Si tout le monde y va de son néologisme sorti de nulle-part (et je crains qu'ils y restent...), les discussions vont être compliquées...