# Articles after "de" in French

Tags: prépositions, articles

One says "fin de semaine" but "Elle parle de l'argent." Why is there no article before "semaine"? Is this just a special expression or is there a part of grammar that adresses this question?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: *À la fin de la semaine, elle parlera d'argent...*

Comment: You've missed out on the existence of partitive articles. French can be thought of as having not two types of articles, but three.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing special with *semaine*:

*Fin de semaine* has a generic meaning. Every week has a *fin de semaine*<sup>1</sup>, same for *fin de journée*, *fin de mois*, *fin de saison*, *fin d'année*, and *fin de siècle*. These expressions name a recurring period of time.

On the other hand *la fin de la semaine* is referring to the same period of a single week, often the current one or the one specified elsewhere (resp. day, month, season, year with *la fin de la journée*, *la fin du mois*, *la fin de la saison*, *la fin du siècle*).

Same with money:

*Elle parle d'agent.* She is talking about money. (in general)

*Elle parle de l'argent.* She is talking about the money. (some money)

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Whether this *fin de semaine* refers to the weekend, one or more workweek days or a combination of both is anecdotal.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

"Fin de semaine" is a noun defined here: [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fin_de_semaine).

1/ (Europe) (Canada) Les deux derniers jours de la semaine de travail : jeudi et vendredi ou le dernier jour de la semaine : vendredi. (Prononcé \fɛ̃ dla smɛn\ au Canada.)

2/ (Canada) (Europe) Ensemble de deux jours, généralement chômés, que constituent le samedi et le dimanche. (Prononcé \fɛ̃ dsə.mɛn\ au Québec.)

In French speaking Canada it is is used for what in French is called "weekend" (2/).

If she is  from Quebec, and if there is no article, then  she means "weekend", unless there is an error.

> Notes (Wiktionnaire)
> Au Canada, traditionnellement, dans le sens 2, le mot week-end n’était pas utilisé, ayant été traduit spontanément par « fin de semaine ». Vers la fin des années 1980, un curieux débat a été soulevé, selon lequel ce mot devait être remplacé en « bon français » par « week-end » puisque seul ce dernier mot figurait dans les dictionnaires normatifs. Le mot « week-end » s’est alors répandu, principalement par le canal du « français radio-canadien ». Aujourd’hui, « week-end » et « fin de semaine » sont à peu près aussi répandus l’un que l’autre, avec sous-jacent le débat entre l’alignement du français québécois sur la norme française et la volonté québécoise d’éviter les emprunts à l’anglais.

See also

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fin_de_semaine)

[Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week-end)
L'expression « fin de semaine » n'est pas nécessairement comprise dans les autres pays francophones , où elle peut désigner les derniers jours de la semaine de travail, par exemple le jeudi et le vendredi, quand la fin de semaine chômé est le samedi et le dimanche. Cependant, si l'on veut désigner les derniers jours de la semaine au Canada francophone, on dira « la fin de la semaine ».

Comment: Je ne pense pas que le mot "week-end" soit souvent employé au Québec, on dit surtout "fin de (la) semaine". Par exemple, _Bonne fin de semaine_

Comment: @Oreste Bonsoir. Vous voulez dire que  « fin de la semaine » est aussi utilisé pour ce que les français appellent «  weekend » ?

Comment: Bonne question... Je crois que "bonne fin de semaine" est beaucoup plus courrant, mais "bonne fin de la semaine" est possible aussi et il signifie _weekend_. Mais vous savez, les articles et moi, ça fait deux, parfois, je les emploie n'importe comment, souvent, je ne les entends même pas. Il faudrait poser cette question à Thélée.

Comment: @Oreste https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/un-mot-fran%c3%a7ais-pour-week-end