# C'est une fin de journée lumineuse / C'est la fin d'une journée lumineuse

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

*J'ai 14 ans et ce n'est pas une bonne nouvelle* de Jo Witek :

> C'est **une** fin de journée lumineuse. Il fait très chaud. Mes tresses
> sont un peu défaites.

Je pense qu'il est aussi possible d'écrire *C'est **la** fin d'**une** journée lumineuse*. Si c'est le cas, quelle est la différence entre ces deux phrases ?

Comment: Le message est le même, la différence est subtile. Le premier est plus générique, tandis que le deuxième mets l'emphase sur la fin.

Comment: @Simon Merci beaucoup.

Comment: La première phrase est positive, optimiste, la deuxième peut être au contraire perçue comme exprimant un regret, une mélancolie.

Comment: J'ai pas tout le contexte, je trouve que ça connote les différences discutées dans les autres commentaires. Mais quand je lis la première phrase, je comprends le sens concret, la lumière, pas de nuages ; dans le deuxième cas je comprends un sens au figuré, positive ? C'est pas tant l'article que probablement le fait de passer d'un truc que je vois comme plus figé à un truc qui l'est moins.

Answer (score 4):

> *Une fin de journée lumineuse*

peut être interprétée de la même manière que

> *C'est la fin d'une journée lumineuse*

dans un contexte où la journée a déjà été décrite comme telle, et on veut mettre l'accent sur le fait que cette journée est terminée (contexte peu commun)

Le plus souvent, dans le premier cas l'adjectif 'lumineuse' se rapporte à la fin de la journée seulement. Cette phrase ne dit rien sur la journée précédente, mais seulement que sa fin est lumineuse.
Dans le second cas,

> *C'est la fin d'une journée lumineuse*

indique que toute la journée a été lumineuse, et n'indique rien sur la luminosité de la fin de journée

Answer (score 0):

Le message est le même, la différence est subtile. Le premier est plus générique, tandis que le deuxième mets l'emphase sur la fin.

(Commentaire de l'utilisateur Simon transformé en réponse).

Answer (score -1):

- C'est une **fin de journée** lumineuse / C'est la **fin d'une journée** lumineuse

Ce qui est changé ce n'est pas seulement l'article du mot « fin » mais c'est aussi celui du mot « journée ».

Il existe une différence qui est matérialisée par  l'usage d'un article  ou son absence devant « journée ». Lorsque  un article est utilisé avant « journée » le sens de « fin » est le suivant (l'article peut être défini ou indéfini).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fin)) **A.** − Ce qui constitue la limite d'une durée ou de tout élément qui peut être considéré relativement à la durée.
> **1.** Ce qui marque la limite terminale de quelque chose.

Lorsqu'un article n'est pas utilisé le sens n'est plus le même ; c'est le suivant.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fin))   **A.** − Ce qui constitue la limite d'une durée ou de tout élément qui peut être considéré relativement à la durée.
> **2.** En partic. Partie terminale d'un ensemble, considérée de manière privilégiée.
> ♦ Fin de journée comme toutes nos fins de journée ici : − La causerie au coin du feu, intime.  (Barb. d'Aurev., Mémor. 3,1856, p. 72)
> ♦ Aussi bien est-ce ce Degas de la fin, libre et décidé, que les peintres modernes aiment.  (Lhote, Peint. d'abord,1942, p. 20)

Dans le premier cas on considère un moment qui se termine lorsque la journée se termine et qui commence près du point que l'on appelle la fin. Dans le second, il s'agit de ce point lui-même. Cependant, le point peut ne pas être exactement un point, mais être concrétisé dans un évènement court, toujours bien plus court que le moment  que l'on appelle la fin de journée.

Pour mieux comprendre, il suffit de considérer l'analogie exacte que l'on trouve dans les termes « fin de la semaine » et « fin de semaine » : la fin de semaine, c'est ce qui est aussi appelé le weekend et qui dure deux jours (samedi, dimanche) ; la fin de la semaine c'est, approximativement le dimanche soir, ou si l'on considère ce que l'on pourrait appeler la fin absolu, c'est le dimanche à minuit.

Il s'ensuit que vous ne pouvez pas faire ce changement sans dire quelque chose de très différent.

Comment: @Oreste Désolé, il y avait beaucoup d'erreurs dans cette réponse et elle n'était probablement pas compréhensible , mais je viens d'y apporter des changements ; ça devrait aller maintenant. En cas de doutes demander des détails.

Comment: L'analogie avec la semaine n'est pas très heureuse. *Fin de semaine/fin de la semaine* n'ont pas le même sens partout. On dirait que tu ne connais pas ceux qu'ils ont en France. Il ne me viendrait jamais à l'idée de penser que la *fin de la semaine*, c'est le dimanche soir. Pour moi, la *fin de semaine*, c'est le jeudi et le vendredi et la *fin de la semaine*, c'est le vendredi soir. Suivant le contexte, le samedi peut être inclus mais le dimanche est "hors semaine", c'est le *week-end*, pas la semaine. Voir [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2118/1109).

Comment: @jlliagre Non, en France le début de la semaine c'est le lundi, et forcément la fin doit se trouver le dimanche soir. Si vous parlez de la semaine de travail, oui, c'est  le vendredi (au soir pour certains, à midi pour d'autres), mais « fin de la semaine » dans ce cas est elliptique : il s'agit véritablement de la semaine de travail.

Comment: @LPH je vous remercie pour votre réponse. // Moi j'aime la prononciation québécoise. Peut-être qu'il n'était pas nécessaire d'exprimer vos gouts en cette matière pour ne pas froisser les Québecois ?